# GCP - how to add labels to VM deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to deploy VM in GCP using deployment manager. I have created a yaml file that contains all the properties, the VM is provisioned ok but with out the labels.

I am using this property in the file

```
tags:
  working-environment-id: vsaworkingenvironment-jwxekh7c
```

Answer (score 0):

you are right, instead of tags you need to use labels. Take a look to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels) for more details.